# gsub back reference and replacement with empty string not identical

Tags: r, gsub

How can I back reference `file_version_1a.csv` in the following?

```
vec = c("dir/file_version_1a.csv")
```

In particular, I wonder why

```
gsub("(file.*csv$)", "", vec)
[1] "dir/"
```

as if I have a correct pattern, yet

```
gsub("(file.*csv$)", "\\1", vec)
[1] "dir/file_version_1a.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *extract* the substring starting with `file` and ending with `csv` at the end of string.

Since `gsub` replaces the match, and you want to use it as an *extraction* function, you need to match *all the text* in the string.

As the text not matched with your regex is at the start of the string, you need to prepend your pattern with `.*` (this matches any zero or more chars, as many as possible, if you use TRE regex in base R functions, and any zero or more chars other than line break chars in PCRE/ICU regexps used in `perl=TRUE` powered base R functions and `stringr`/`stringi` functions):

```
vec = c("dir/file_version_1a.csv")
gsub(".*(file.*csv)$", "\\1", vec)
```

However, `stringr::str_extract` seems a more natural choice here:

```
stringr::str_extract(vec, "file.*csv$")
regmatches(vec, regexpr("file.*csv$",vec))
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##TYzRCsIwDEXf9xWl7CEdo7LXgX8yKDXGWtApSVf29zVDEJ@S3HNzuLVKaM4GwV4zn275QaESS36tYYoepVrXJdkuYP0AB/aDhq63o7HLMulQgeukcF4Tz7MugfbCEQso0dbvqVcVU3rGgneSL9Wb9jfDf2s8jK61Dw).

Comment: Perfect answer, I agree that `str_extract` is more natural choice. Meanwhile, I arrived at not so clean workaround (as it is not looking for match!) so just for the record: `gsub("(^dir*.)", "\\2", vec)`

Comment: @ValloVarik You must have meant [`sub("^dir/", "", vec)`](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyw1WcFWIVlDKSWzSD8tMyc1viy1qDgzPy/eMFEvubhMSZOruDRJQykOJK@ko6AExEA9mv//AwA). There is no Group 2 in your regex.

Comment: It does not make sense to me too, but somehow [referring to Group 2 works](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyw1WcFWIVlDKSWzSD8tMyc1viy1qDgzPy/eMFEvubhMSZOruDRJQykOJK@ko6AExEA9mv//AwA). I discovered via trial-and-error (read: out of despair :) ) that `gsub("(file.*csv$)", "\\2", vec)` gives me `[1] "dir/"` and took it from there...

Comment: @ValloVarik There is no Group 2 in your regex pattern and `\2` is an empty string. Replacing with `"\\2"` is the same as replacing with `""`. The parentheses are thus totally redundant (you are not using Group 1 anywhere in the replacement) and the `r*` matches any 0 or more `r` letters, and `.` matches any char. Look at [what your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/zG7wBz/1).

Comment: I understand what you're saying and agree. But I tried `gsub("(^dir*.)", "\\2", vec)` even on the very tio.run environment you posted, and it worked there, too.

Comment: @ValloVarik :) I do not say it won't "work", I just explained you *how* it works, so that you are not surprised when you match something weird. You know, you may match `a` with `(?=a)[a-z0-9!@$#^%^*&()+_]` or with `a`, it is up to you how much you want to "obfuscate" your regex methods.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your comment initially. All clear now. Thanks a lot for removing the "obfuscation" from my thinking, I'll remove it now from my code too :)